# Content-type is blank in the headers of some requests

Tags: python, http, get, python-requests, content-type

I've ran this queries millions (yes, millions) of times before with other URLs. However, I'm getting a KeyError when checking the content-type of the following webpage.

Code snippet:

```
r = requests.get("http://health.usnews.com/health-news/articles/2014/10/15/limiting-malpractice-claims-may-not-curb-costly-medical-tests", timeout=10, headers=headers)
if "text/html" in r.headers["content-type"]:
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'content-type'
```

I checked the content of `r.headers` and it's:

```
CaseInsensitiveDict({'date': 'Fri, 20 May 2016 06:44:19 GMT', 'content-length': '0', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'server': 'BigIP'})
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all servers set a Content-Type header. Use `.get()` to retrieve a default if it is missing:

```
if "text/html" in r.headers.get("content-type", ''):
```

For the URL you gave I can't reproduce this:

```
$ curl -s -D - -o /dev/null "http://health.usnews.com/health-news/articles/2014/10/15/limiting-malpractice-claims-may-not-curb-costly-medical-tests"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Brightspot
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 20 May 2016 06:45:12 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A0C35776067AABCF9E029150C64D8D91; Path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

but if the header is missing from *your* response then it usually isn't Python's fault, and certainly not your code's fault.

It could be you encountered a buggy server or temporary glitch, or the server you contacted doesn't like you for one reason or another. Your sample response headers have the content-length set to 0 as well, for example, indicating there was no content to serve at all.

The server that gave you that response is `BigIP`, a [load balancer / network router product from a company called F5](https://f5.com/products/big-ip/). Hard to say exactly what kind (they have global routing servers as well as per-datacenter or cluster load balancers). It could be that the load balancer ran out of back-end servers to serve the request, doesn't have servers in your region, or the load balancer decided that you are sending too many requests and refuses to give you more than just this response, or it is the wrong phase of the moon and Jupiter is in retrograde and it threw a tantrum. We can't know!

But, just in case this happens again, do also look at the response status code. It may well be a [4xx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) or [5xx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) status code indicating that something was wrong with your request or with the server. For example, a 429 status code response would indicate you made too many requests in a short amount of time and should slow down. Test for it by checking `r.status_code`.

Comment: Would it perhaps be due to throttling of requests from a single IP? PS: You are a brilliant man.

Comment: @User: could be, hard to say. HTTP servers are black boxes, they can respond how they damn well please. I note that the `Server`header also differs for us.

Comment: I have found that it's possible to put the call to requests.get() inside a try/catch block, and if the key error occurs, the catch code pauses for a few seconds and repeats the call.  This works 99.9999% of the time.